# How do I install NanoBSD on a flashdrive?

Tags: unix, freebsd, embedded

I would like to install NanoBSD on a flashdrive, I'm on a Linux Machine and don't have an extra machine around. I'm very used to Linux but I'd like to try out NanoBSD on a headless machine of mine. I've read the official documentation but can't figure out how to do it. If someone can perhaps point me to a very step by step tutorial (that a Linux person would understand), I thought it could probably work if I install it to the hardrive of the virtualmachine and use clonezilla to put it on a usb flashdrive. Also :more info: I'd like to have it configured with a static ip and have sshd start up at boot time, or atleast be able to connect via serial port. I've tried pfsense, but I'm specifically looking for nanobsd , not the pfsense version which seems to be aimed more at building routers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to generate a NanoBSD image from a FreeBSD machine. It can't be done from Linux. But it can be done from a virtual machine running FreeBSD.

As explained in the [NanoBSD HOWTO](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/nanobsd/howto.html), the `nanobsd.sh` script creates an image file called `_.disk.full`. If you are running FreeBSD on a virtual machine, you'll have to copy the image file to your real machine. (How to do that depends on the virtualization program you're using.) Then you can use `dd` to transfer it to a flash device.

But if both the Linux machine and the headless machine have serial ports, you can connect them using a [null modem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem) cable, and just install a regular FreeBSD from the serial console. That would be much less complicated.